# jQuery Error in Drag and Drop?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I'm trying to change the order of Articles in the Article Manager within Joomla.

As soon as I attempt to drag an article I get glitches of varying types.

In console, I am getting this error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr[sortable-group-id=47,56,61]

The numbers of the group ID are different depending on which row I'm attempting to drag.

Has anyone seen this issue, or can provide pointers to the possible cause?

Joomla is fully up to date as is jQuery.

Comment: Have you ensured you're using Joomla 3.4.4 (latest version)?

Comment: Yes absolutely positive.

Comment: Would it be possible that you have installed a plugin that produce a jQuery conflict?

Comment: Hi Piero, yes I thought so too but we have disabled and uninstalled plugins that also used jQuery, and it made no difference.  Also, of note, is that we CAN change the order of Modules without any errors - it's only Articles that cause an issue.  Oddly, today, the 3-box icon for dragging, has vanished from the Article Manager.